# Get Picture to userform Excel VBA show no difference in 64 bit Window 10

Tags: excel, vba, image, dll, clipboard

I'm using 64bit office in 64bit window 10 PC.
I did googling and found below sample code to load picture from current clipboard to userform but there is no change. ( image don't appear to userform image control)

Firstly I doubt about the dll referencing because I can't manually add reference using tools > reference command in VBE.

So I used `regsvr32 C:\windows\system32 oleaut32.dll` in administrator mode and now succeeded but still can't get clipboard image to userform.

I changed a little code and simplified it and below is the final one.
I'll appreciated it if anybody can give me a simple clue.

I did some modification

```
'***************************************************************************'*
'* AUTHOR & DATE:   STEPHEN BULLEN, Office Automation Ltd
'*                  15 November 1998


'*
'* DESCRIPTION:     Creates a standard Picture object from whatever is on the clipboard.
'*                  This object can then be assigned to (for example) and Image control
'*                  on a userform.  The PastePicture function takes an optional argument of
'*                  the picture type - xlBitmap or xlPicture.
'*
'*                  The code requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library
'*
'*                  The code in this module has been derived from a number of sources
'*                  discovered on MSDN.
'*
'*                  To use it:
'*                      Set Image1.Picture = PastePicture(xlPicture)
'*                  to paste a picture of whatever is on the clipboard into a standard image control.
'*
'* PROCEDURES:
'*   PastePicture   The entry point for the routine
'*   CreatePicture  Private function to convert a bitmap or metafile handle to an OLE reference
'*   fnOLEError     Get the error text for an OLE error code
'***************************************************************************

Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type


Public Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hPic As LongPtr
    hPal As LongPtr
End Type

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr 'Correct wFormat type is integer or long???
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As LongPtr, IPic As IPicture) As LongPtr
    ' In here, I tried manual referencing via tools > reference but can't, the error says
    '      "Can't add a reference to the specified file"
    ' Or can I use regsvr32 oleaut32.dll command in cmd window instead ??
    ' I already did regsvr32 registration and succeeeded but function still not working .
        
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" (ByVal hemfSrc As LongPtr, ByVal lpszFile As String) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal Handle As LongPtr, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As LongPtr
 

Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4

Public Function PastePicture(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As IPicture
  PastePictureVBA7 (lXlPicType)
End Function

Public Function PastePictureVBA7(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As IPicture

    Dim H As Long, hPicAvail As Long, hPtr As LongPtr, hPal As LongPtr, lPicType As Long, hCopy As LongPtr  ''Correct lPicType type is integer or long???
    
    lPicType = IIf(lXlPicType = xlBitmap, CF_BITMAP, CF_ENHMETAFILE)
    hPicAvail = IsClipboardFormatAvailable(lPicType)
    
    If hPicAvail <> 0 Then
        H = OpenClipboard(0&)
    
        If H > 0 Then
            hPtr = GetClipboardData(lPicType)
            
            If lPicType = CF_BITMAP Then
                hCopy = CopyImage(hPtr, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG)
            Else
                hCopy = CopyEnhMetaFile(hPtr, vbNullString)
            End If
            
       
            H = CloseClipboard
            If hPtr <> 0^ Then Set PastePictureVBA7 = CreatePictureVBA7(hCopy, 0, lPicType)
        End If
    End If
End Function

Public Function CreatePictureVBA7(ByVal hPic As LongPtr, ByVal hPal As LongPtr, ByVal lPicType) As IPicture

        Dim r As LongPtr, uPicInfo As uPicDesc, IID_IDispatch As GUID, IPic As IPicture
        Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
        Const PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE = 4
        
        With IID_IDispatch
            .Data1 = &H7BF80980
            .Data2 = &HBF32
            .Data3 = &H101A
            .Data4(0) = &H8B
            .Data4(1) = &HBB
            .Data4(2) = &H0
            .Data4(3) = &HAA
            .Data4(4) = &H0
            .Data4(5) = &H30
            .Data4(6) = &HC
            .Data4(7) = &HAB
        End With
        
        With uPicInfo
            .Size = Len(uPicInfo)
            .Type = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, PICTYPE_BITMAP, PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE)
            .hPic = hPic
            .hPal = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, hPal, 0)
        End With

        r = OleCreatePictureIndirect(uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, 1, IPic)
        'Is there somting wrong in here ???
        
        If r = 0 Then
           Set CreatePictureVBA7 = IPic
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so please [edit] your question, add the error message you get and tell in which line you get an error.

Comment: HI, Peh thanks. I'm new to here and i edited contents^^

Comment: PEH, problem here is code shows no difference even I update the Longptr where you pointed out. Could you give me any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your declaration to:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As LongPtr
```

> as Greg formerly pointed out in a comment I was wrong and according to the official documentation of the [OleCreatePictureIndirect function (olectl.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/olectl/nf-olectl-olecreatepictureindirect) `fPictureOwnsHandle` is boolean and therefore has to be `Long`.

Be aware that this function does nothing:

```
Public Function PastePicture(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As IPicture
    PastePictureVBA7 (lXlPicType)
End Function
```

because it just runs `PastePictureVBA7` but then it does not return the picture as return value of the function `PastePicture`. So the picture gets dismissed and `PastePicture` returns always `Nothing`. To make it return the picture from `PastePictureVBA7` you would need to change it to:

```
Public Function PastePicture(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As
    Set PastePicture = PastePictureVBA7(lXlPicType)
End Function
```

but then you can actually run `PastePictureVBA7` directly because it does exactly the same.

If I add an image box `Image1` in a new userform and run

```
Image1.Picture = PastePictureVBA7
```

after copying a range in VBA it gets displayed as an image in the image box.

[image]

Comment: this eliminate my recent headache. I really appreciate your kindness. meanwhile Am I and other user need to do enroll oleaut32.dll using regsvr32 ? or the VBA code itself is enough for distribution ?

Comment: @PlaylearnKim I did use a default Windows 10 install with a default Office 2019 install. No ddl registering was required, just the code itself.