# Create Print Preview Within UserForm in Image Control Box

Tags: excel, vba, userform

The code should show a preview image within Image Control box named Image1 on the same userform.

There's a hold up at

```
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Environ("TEMP") & "\\PrintPreview.png")
```

I checked the Temp directory. It is saving the PrintPreview.png file as PrintPreview.png.pdf so it can't load it to the Image control box.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Hide
    
    ' Create a temporary worksheet to hold the print area
    Dim tempSheet As Worksheet
    Set tempSheet = Sheets.Add
    
    ' Copy the desired range to the temporary sheet
    Worksheets("InputSheet").Range("A1:I31").Copy tempSheet.Range("A1")
    
    ' Set print area for the temporary sheet
    tempSheet.PageSetup.printArea = tempSheet.UsedRange.Address
    
    ' Create a chart to capture a screenshot of the print preview
    Dim tempChart As ChartObject
    Set tempChart = tempSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, tempSheet.UsedRange.Width, tempSheet.UsedRange.Height)
    
    ' Copy the temporary sheet to the chart
    tempChart.Chart.Paste
    
    ' Export the chart as an image
    tempChart.Chart.Export Environ("TEMP") & "\PrintPreview.png", "PNG"
    
    ' Delete the temporary sheet and chart
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tempSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Load the captured image into the Image control
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Environ("TEMP") & "\PrintPreview.png")
    
    ' Show the UserForm again
    Me.Show
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I expect a PrintPreview.png image to appear in image control box "Image1" on the same userform.

Comment: I don't want to say this is a duplicate to this question. But as I have understood it, the function PastePicture can paste images in image objects on a userform https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567567/get-picture-to-userform-excel-vba-show-no-difference-in-64-bit-window-10

Comment: png is not accepted by Picture. Try to convert it to 24bit bmp with e.g. Paint.

Comment: @Blackcat I believe the whole idea is to do it with code and not manually

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by BlackCat, VBA does not natively handle PNG files.

The following function can be used which minimal changes to your code above:

```vb
Function LoadImage(ByVal Filename As String) As StdPicture
    With CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
        .LoadFile Filename
        Set LoadImage = .FileData.Picture
    End With
End Function
```

Change the relevant line of code to:

```
Image1.Picture = LoadImage(Environ("TEMP") & "\PrintPreview.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented yet but I know how to go about it.

1. First, I create a sheet and with a blank chart.
2. Then I copy the desired range into the chart
3. Next I export the chart as an PNG Image to a directory on my PC
4. Lastly I import onto my Image Control on my form thus creating a preview

Copy Range to Chart

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chartObject As chartObject
    Dim img As Shape
    Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rngToCopy As Range      

    ' Set the worksheet with the chart
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet28")

    ' Set the chart object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set chartObject = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 3")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Set the worksheet with the input data
    Set inputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InputSheet")

    ' Set the range to copy
    Set rngToCopy = inputSheet.Range("A1:I31")

    ' Check if the chart object exists
    If Not chartObject Is Nothing Then
        ' Clear existing fill
        chartObject.Chart.ChartArea.Interior.Pattern = xlNone

        ' Copy the range as a picture
        rngToCopy.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

        ' Paste the picture onto the worksheet
        ws.Paste

        ' Set the img variable to the newly pasted shape
        Set img = ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count)

        ' Move the image to the chart area
        img.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        img.Width = chartObject.Width
        img.Height = chartObject.Height
        img.Top = chartObject.Top
        img.Left = chartObject.Left

        ' Clear the clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Chart 3 not found on Sheet28", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Export Chart to Image File

```vb
Sub ExportChartAsPNG()
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Dim chartFilePath As String

    ' Set the chart object
    Set myChart = Sheets("Sheet28").ChartObjects("Chart 3")

    ' Specify the file path for the exported PNG image
    chartFilePath = "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder\Chart3.png"  ' Update the path as needed

    ' Export the chart as PNG
    myChart.Chart.Export Filename:=chartFilePath, FilterName:="PNG"

    ' Inform the user about the successful export
    MsgBox "Chart 3 has been exported as PNG to " & chartFilePath, vbInformation
End Sub
```